# astrolog make from source results in 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

Tags: macos, high-sierra, xcode, x11, open-source

**OS:** High Sierra 10.13.6
**Software:** [astrolog](http://www.astrolog.org/astrolog/astfile.htm)

```
ast65src$ make
c++  -O -Wno-write-strings -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment  -c -o astrolog.o astrolog.cpp
In file included from astrolog.cpp:50:
./astrolog.h:304:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [astrolog.o] Error 1
```

xcode command line tools are already installed:

```
ast65src$ sudo xcode-select --install

xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

I tried the following fix, but the same error resulted:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/

make ARCH=macosx -I/opt/X11/include
```

Comment: Editing the `Makefile` line 30 to `CPPFLAGS = -O -Wno-write-strings -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -I/opt/X11/include` gets it further (compiles but fails on linking).  Did you edit the `astrolog.h`?

Comment: Do you have the X11 files installed under /opt/X11?  They are not part of xcode.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - good point.  In my case the X11 files in /opt come from [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) - I assumed OP had it installed.

Comment: Linking can be fixed by adding `LDLIBS = -L/opt/X11/lib` to Makefile and adding it to the `CC` line.  It may be more convenient to download the pre-compiled command line Macintosh version (*ast65mac.out*) from the [Astrolog Downloads](http://www.astrolog.org/astrolog/astfile.htm) page.   It works fine on Mojave.